# how to make div glide down and then go immediately back up to the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a div glide down and go back up immideately after its done. This is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var divtofall = $('.divtofall');
   function fall() {
       divtofall.animate({top:'+=500'}, 10000);
     }
 function gobackup() {
       divtofall.css('top', '0px');
     }

fall();

gobackup();


});
```

And this is my css:

```
#div1{ width:200px; height:200px;position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px;}
```

However it is just gliding down and not coming back up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling `gobackup()`, the animation is still not finished, then the top property will be overridden.

Instead, call it as the callback parameter of the `.animate()` method:

[**JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/gv73600g/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var divtofall = $('.divtofall');
    function gobackup() {
        divtofall.css('top', '0px');
    }

    function fall() {
        divtofall.animate({top:'+=500'}, 10000, gobackup);
    }

    fall();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the animation needs some time to be executed, so when `gobackup()` is called, the animation is still there. You can solve by this way:

```
$(function(){
    var divtofall = $('.divtofall');

    divtofall.animate({top:'+=500'}, 10000, function(){
        //$(this).css('top', 0);
        $(this).animate({ top: 0 }, 5000);
    });

   // divtofall.animate({top:'+=500'}, 10000).animate({ top: 0 }, 5000); works too
});
```

[Check jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/2mkx3odk/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 divtofall.animate({top:'+=500'}, 10000, function(){
   gobackup()
 });
```

Try this above. I don't think .css will animate your div. Also, you can call the function upon completion by adding an anoymous function at the end of .animate

Comment: Sorry if the question was unclear but i just want it to glide down with animation and then immideately come back up without any animation.

Answer (score 0):

you can chain animate in jquery:

`divtofall.animate({top:'+=500'}, 1000).animate({top:'-=500'}, 1000);`